# Permission Denied error on f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to learn how to use f2py (Fortran to Python), but I am getting a permission denied error when I use f2py and I am the admin user.
`!f2py -c -m hellofortran hellofortran.f`
then I get the error:

`/bin/sh: /Users/dorislee/.virtualenvs/py27dev/bin/f2py: Permission denied`

I tried doing `sudo easy_install numpy` but that it still says Permission denied

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to use "sudo" to install packages locally in your own home directory. This will make those directories owned by the root user. You might check if any directories in .virtualenvs are owned by root, and if so, change the ownership back to your own user.

Comment: If you do `ls -l /Users/dorislee/.virtualenvs/py27dev/bin/f2py` what do you get?  Is the execute bit set for you?  Is it readable?

Comment: Same problem here